# excluding words with consecutive repeat characters

Tags: regex

Say I have a list of words like this: mouse, abba, roar, accent

I need a regex that will match mouse and roar, but not abba or accent, because the last two have consecutive repeat characters (bb and cc).

I managed to come up with the following pattern to match only the words WITH double consecutive characters:

```
.*(.)\1.*
```

However what I need is the opposite, but I am having a hard time inverting it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use this:

```
\b(?:([a-z])(?!\1))+\b
```

it use a negative lookahead `(?!..)` which tests that each capture is not followed by itself. To be sure that the pattern doesn't cut a word before the word end or begin in the middle of a word, I added word boundaries `\b` on each side.

An other way:

```
(?![a-z]*([a-z])\1)\b[a-z]+\b
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works. I'll try to understand it now!

Comment: @DanielS: It's easy to understand when you keep in mind that a lookahead is only a check and is not part of the match result.

Comment: Gotcha the part about the lookahead. Why the ?: though?

Comment: @DanielS: `(?:..)` is only a non capturing group. I use it to enclose each character with the lookahead assertion. I repeat this group (`+`), thus each characters are checked one by one.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this lookahead based regex:

```
^(?:(.)(?!\1))*$
```

Comment: Hmm. For some reason on regexpal.com is doesn't work. I'll check on my local machine, thanks.

Comment: Sure just make sure you use `g` and `m` flags

Comment: @anubhava: congratulations for your 100k :-)